# USB-C Power Delivery charging not working on Linux

Tags: fedora, usb, power-management

I recently had my laptop serviced, and the motherboard was replaced.
I run a dual boot setup with Fedora Linux and Windows.

Before the servicing, the USB-C port supported charging on Linux via Power Delivery.
However, afterwards, charging via USB-C PD exhibits some peculiar behaviour:

- Works fine on Windows
- Works fine when laptop is plugged in while powered off
- Does not charge on Linux if laptop boots without USB-C plugged in, charging
- Charges fine on Linux if laptop was already plugged in before booting (even charges after plugging out and plugging in)

To summarise, I have to have the laptop plugged in via a USB-C charger, if I want the laptop to be able to charge for this boot/session, where it will continue to work even if I plug out the USB-C charger and plug it in another time.

Clearly Linux still supports charging via USB-C, but cannot initiate the charging if the conditions above aren't met.

The result of
`cat /sys/class/typec/port0/power_role` is `[source] sink` even when plugged in.
USB-C accessories still work with the port.

What is going on and how can I rectify this issue?

Thank you.